# accessing controls on parentform from childform

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change text in textbox on  parentform from childform.
I set textbox

modifiers= public 
i have extra written a function in parentform

```
public TextBox txtbox
{
  get
  {
    return  mybox;
  }
  set
  {
    mybox= value;
  }
}
```

in child form on writing
  this.ParentForm. ( can't see mybox).
what i am missing.
regards,

Comment: Just a note but this looks like a design that gas gone wrong. A childform should not have to access Parent controls.

Comment: As Henk mentioned its not a practical design. try using an 'event' instead.

Comment: Child Form means,Parent Form holds another form inside it? or you are talking about inheritance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `ParentForm` will return a `Form` and not *your* form, you need to cast it before you can access any of your custom properties:

```
((MyForm)this.ParentForm).textbox = "new text!";
```

Additionally, you are setting the *whole* control, not just the text.

Try this, to expose the text property only:

```
public string txtbox
{
  get
  {
    return  mybox.Text;
  }
  set
  {
    mybox.Text = value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that ParentForm is of type Form which does not have a member txtbox. You need to cast ParentForm to your form (suppose it is Form1), like:

```
((Form1)this.ParentForm).txtbox
```

Answer (score 0):

Random guess without seeing any actual code: `mybox` is likely not declared public.

Edit: Or, ah, yes, as Andrei says - you havn't cast the ParentForm to your parent form's type.