# C# Changing Button Text from form2

Tags: c#, forms, button, text, textbox

I have the problem that I don't found working things that I can change my button text from form 1 
I want to change the text from the button from form 1 with a textbox from form2

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow, we don't do your homework, please read [How Do i ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Or, better, google the question. It comes up here 10-20 times every single day. (Hint: you need a) references to the other forms, eg by passing it into the constructor and b) make the fields you want to access public.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13470018/10223668) link. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change label text of parent form from child form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469957/change-label-text-of-parent-form-from-child-form)

Answer (score 2):

first change the form 1 button modifiers to public,

[image: Modifiers]

[image: Modifiers]

then add this code to your project

```
Form1.button.Text = "Your Text";
```